# bootstrap datetimepicker position is wrong

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have the following html generated

```
<form action="/Home/UpdateMeetingWithId" method="post">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="P-Ijqa8mk1lgxnRGypuf84s6p76pktsoZvTVHrvyc7MXCUMw8vvLUOfjJ-qfV-JrtaY_GpFDfjUKCbR2Qkjt_Q0i21WHK13cc7gSu-64qYfbMIlZnqZBI7nvbD3UNcIDZwaxkTHRFA9KMzJDJpfaWw2" />                
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td>Start time</td>
            <td>End time</td>
            <td>Notify host by</td>
            <td>Reason</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Fri 05 Aug 2016 14:00</td>
            <td>Fri 05 Aug 2016 15:00</td>
            <td>
               SMS
            </td>
            <td>sdfsd</td>
            <td nowrap>
               <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/ReinviteVisitor?meetingIdToEdit=7&amp;visitorId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&amp;email=sdfs%40asdf.com">Edit</a>
               <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/DeleteMeetingWithId?meetingId=7" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you wish to delete this meeting?&#39;);">Delete</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td nowrap>
               <input class="form-control datetimepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start Time must be a date." data-val-required="The Start Time field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_StartTime" name="MeetingToEdit.StartTime" type="text" value="05/08/2016 14:20" />
               <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MeetingToEdit.StartTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
               <input class="form-control datetimepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field End Time must be a date." data-val-required="The End Time field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_EndTime" name="MeetingToEdit.EndTime" type="text" value="05/08/2016 15:30" />
               <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MeetingToEdit.EndTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The On visitor arrival field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_HostNotificationMethod" name="MeetingToEdit.HostNotificationMethod">
                  <option selected="selected" value="SMS">SMS</option>
                  <option value="CALL">CALL</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Reason for invitation field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_Title" name="MeetingToEdit.Title" type="text" value="sdfds" />
               <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MeetingToEdit.Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
               <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_Id" name="MeetingToEdit.Id" type="hidden" value="4" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_SubjectId" name="MeetingToEdit.SubjectId" type="hidden" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
               <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_FirstName" name="MeetingToEdit.FirstName" type="hidden" value="sdf" />
               <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_LastName" name="MeetingToEdit.LastName" type="hidden" value="sdf" />
               <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_Email" name="MeetingToEdit.Email" type="hidden" value="sdfs@asdf.com" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_Company" name="MeetingToEdit.Company" type="hidden" value="dsf" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostFirstName" name="MeetingToEdit.HostFirstName" type="hidden" value="neee" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostLastName" name="MeetingToEdit.HostLastName" type="hidden" value="Admin" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostEmail" name="MeetingToEdit.HostEmail" type="hidden" value="admin@admin.com" />
               <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostMobile" name="MeetingToEdit.HostMobile" type="hidden" value="+61400000014" />
               <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/ReinviteVisitor?visitorId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&amp;email=sdfs%40asdf.com">Cancel</a>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

But the datetimepicker is in the wrong positions. See screenshot below:
[image]

It gets worse as the there is more rows in the table. The further down the textbox for the datetimepicker is, the higher the datetimepicker gets. Weird issue, anyone see what is going on here?

UPDATE:
As per comments this is what I have but it is not working still

```
$("#meetingstable").on("click", "td", function () {
        $("#MeetingToEdit_StartTime").datetimepicker({ widgetParent: this });
});
```

Also how modify the above to handle the two datetimepickers i.e MeetingToEdit_StartTime and MeetingToEdit_EndTime they will depend on which cell is clicked.

Comment: Can you change the `widgetParent` property on cell click and make the parent to be that cell..? the cell should have `position: relative`. It seems that widget is now using the table as parent. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetparent

Comment: Another option is to show the widget inside external popup (like bootstrap modal)  and use picker¨s `inline: true` option inside that modal.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean in the first comment?

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` to TD.. just for fun :) i think it should work.. then you can remove that click handler also.. picker popup is using absolute positioning (i quess) so it needs relative positioned parent to work. You can also check that there is no margin etc extra spacing in popup css (see console). Maybe some other class is messing up the position.

Comment: that worked, that is what I ended up doing

Comment: @Hardy, please post a proper answer so this post can be resolved.